# PrimeNG p-chips delete only

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using p-chips of primeNG with Angular 2.
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/chips

My p-chips is filled when selecting value of a multi-select list.
I would like to disable the addition of data by writing in the p-chips.

But I want to keep the possibility of deleting values.

Is it possible ? 
Otherwise do you know any other tool which can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No built in way to do this.  You could probably add a delete-only property to the component to make it function the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve it using CSS:

```
/* +++++++ Prime NG CHIPS +++++++ */
.ui-chips > ul.ui-inputtext,
.ui-chips > ul.ui-inputtext:focus {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: none;
}
.ui-chips .ui-chips-input-token {
  display: none;
}
```

or SCSS:

```
/* +++++++ Prime NG CHIPS +++++++ */
.ui-chips {
  > ul.ui-inputtext,
  > ul.ui-inputtext:focus {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: none;
  }
  .ui-chips-input-token {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

please note, that these CSS rules should be added to some global (uncapsulated) CSS/SCSS file

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mugxwj?file=styles.css

**2022 UPDATE**
I did not check primeng for a while, but I see you can achieve the same by using `max` property:

```
<p-chips [max]="values?.length || 0" [(ngModel)]="values" ></p-chips>
```

keep in mind that when max is 0, you can add one chip, if this is not desired, consider disabling `p-chip` with `disabled` property

Comment: As for 2022, the correct css tags seems to be 'p-chips' instead of 'ui-chips'

Comment: @Maniax, please see my 2022 update, maybe it will fit your task better